# Concatenating a #EVAL to a OnClientClick function

Tags: asp.net, eval, asplinkbutton, onclientclick

I'm trying to concatenate an Eval data to an OnClientClick function. What I did is this:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="Activate" runat="server" OnClientClick='return confirmActivate(<%# Eval("nameID")%>);'>Activate</asp:LinkButton>
```

But it shows the code of Eval inside when I inspect it's element. How could I put nameID's data inside the OnClientClick function??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Eval with format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Activate" runat="server"
    OnClientClick='<%# Eval("nameID", "return confirmActivate(\"{0}\")") %>'>
    Activate
</asp:LinkButton>
```